# Load images with special characters defined in .plist

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a .plist with a lot of names.
A table view displays all the information from the .plist.
Also an image with the same name as the string is added to the cell.

Almost everything works fine, just the names that have special characters does not show the image.

Working:
`<string>The Name</string>`
I have an image called "The Name.png"

It Works.

Not Working:
`<string>The Name vs. "Me"</string>`
I have an image called "The Name vs. "Me".png"

The image does not show up.

Why ?
How can I make it work ?

Thanks.

Adding the info requested.

Plist.
`<dict>`
`<key>Name</key>`
`<string>A</string>`
`<key>type</key>`
`<array>`
`<string>The Name</string>`
`<string>The Name vs. "Me"</string>`
`</array>`
`</dict>`

Code to call the image to the cell.
`UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)];`
`imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:nombreDeDOEnFila];`
`cell.imageView.image = imgView.image;`

More code to show how its being used.

`// Configure the cell.`
`NSString *nombreDeDOEnFila = [type objectAtIndex:row];`
`cell.textLabel.text = nombreDeDOEnFila;`

`// Call image`
`UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)];`
`imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:nombreDeDOEnFila];`
`cell.imageView.image = imgView.image;`

`#pragma mark - Table view delegate`

`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        {`

`NSString *nombreDeDOEnFila = [type objectAtIndex:row];`
`moreInfoController.name = nombreDeDOEnFila;`

Comment: can you post relevant code on how you use the .plist as well as displaying the image.

Comment: Sure thing, I just updated it with the code. Thanks.

Comment: how is `nombreDeDOEnFila` being set? can you show the code for that? Are you reading it out of the plist?

Comment: I just update it with that code. I think that has nothing to do with special characters for the image, but for sure you know more about that. Thanks.

Comment: Silly question but what is the value of `nombreDeDOEnFila` when you make this call `imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:nombreDeDOEnFila];`

Comment: How can I get the value ? (sorry, I am really new.)

Comment: no worries. Set a break point on that line of code and inspect the value: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#recipes/xcode_help-source_editor/Creating,Disabling,andDeletingBreakpoints/Creating,Disabling,andDeletingBreakpoints.html

Answer (score 0):

The string in the plist editor is the unescaped string. You will have to escape the quotes

`<string>The Name vs. \"Me\"</string>`

Comment: Thanks Joe, but it's not working doing it that way.
In the cell I see the name displaying like this: The Name vs. \"Me\" and the image is still not appearing.